# Fiddler: The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol,

Tags: azure, fiddler, azure-cosmosdb

I want to query DocumentDB in Fiddler

So as mentioned in this link, i am using POST method as follows

URL: https://documebtdbaccount:443/dbs/ToDoList/colls/Items/docs

> User-Agent: Fiddler
>
> Host: documentdbaccount:443
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> x-ms-date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 06:15:00 GMT
>
> x-ms-version: 2016-07-11
>
> authorization: type=master&ver=1.0&sig=masterkey
>
> Content-Type: application/query+json
>
> Accept: application/json
>
> x-ms-documentdb-isquery: True

I am getting below error, not sure what it is about

> message=The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please
>   check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and
>   check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign:
>   'post docs dbs/ToDoList/colls/Items tue, 10 jan 2017 05:43:20 gmt
>
> '

ActivityId: a0df52a6-1629-4437-8d15-c82eb02df278

Comment: I think the issue is that you're using masterkey as token signature. Please see this link on how you can create a token signature for your request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources.

Comment: It seems i am missing something here
I added ResourceType: docs, ResourceId: Items (collection name)
But still same error

Can you please let me what i a missing here because i have mentioned all input as mentioned in said link in example.

Comment: `i have mentioned all input as mentioned in said link in example` - Which link are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I thought i have mentioned link above
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api

I was talking about this link

Comment: Did you construct the hashed signature token?  The authorization header for each operation must have a valid hashed signature token as noted in the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources

Answer (score 0):

Check your object ID for any prohibited characters.
As per [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/35d39f79-a846-4973-92dd-044f5bd1e9c4/documentclientexception-the-input-authorization-token-cant-serve-the-request?forum=azurecosmosdb):

```
The following characters are not supported for the Id property of document: '/', '\\', '?', '#'.
Also, Id cannot end with an empty space.
```

I've had an extra white space character at the very end of the payload object ID.
It introduces a mismatch between the POST URL (which doesn't has this trailing space) and the actual payload content (which still has it). Thus this error appeared. Removing the trailing space fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Check your authorization key that you are passing in.